# Write contents of custom View to large Image file on SD card

Tags: android

I have a class that extends View.  I override the onDraw method and allow the user to draw on the screen.  I am at the point where I want to save this view as an image.  I Can use buildDrawingCache and getDrawingCache to create a bitmap that I can write to the SD card.  However, the image is not good quality at a large size, it has jagged edges.  Since I have a View and I use Paths I can transform all by drawing to a bigger size.  I just don't know how to make the Canvas bigger so when I call getDrawingCache it doesn't crop all the paths I am just transformed.  What is happening is I transform all my paths but when I write the Bitmap to file I am only getting the "viewport" of the actual screen size.  I want something much bigger.  Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  I have been reading the docs and books and am at a loss.
Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another Canvas backed by a Bitmap that you create and draw all the paths to that.  Then the Bitmap will hold the larger, higher resolution image.  It would look something like this:

```
Bitmap largeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas largeCanvas = new Canvas(largeBitmap);

// Draw the paths to this canvas and then use largeBitmap to save to a file.
```